# How to upgrade Priority to log4j-2?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to upgrade log4j to log4j2. The particular line of code I am trying to upgrade is:

```
log(targetClass, Priority.DEBUG_INT, message, null);
```

The static field `Priority.DEBUG_INT` is no longer available in the new `Priority`. Instead it looks like the `getPriority(Facility facility, org.apache.logging.log4j.Level level)` static method is used to access priority int value, to which `DEBUG` can be specified as the `Level`.

However, this method also requires a `Facility` to be specified. How do I know which `Facility` to specify when calling `getPriority`?

---

old Priority: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Priority.html
new Priority: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/net/Priority.html
new Facility: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.8/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/net/Facility.html

Comment: [this](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/net/Facility.html)? If these are your messages, it surely looks like `1`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about Log4j 1's [`Category.log(String, Priority, Object, Throwable)`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#log(java.lang.String,%20org.apache.log4j.Priority,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Throwable)), it appears these `Priority` classes are pretty (if not completely) unrelated. Log4j 1's `Priority` is actually the *level* (indeed it has a subclass `Level`).

So you would have to look at Log4j 2's [`Logger`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html) class to see if any method with `Level` parameter matches, but there appears to be no identical alternative (except [`logMessage`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html#logMessage-org.apache.logging.log4j.Level-org.apache.logging.log4j.Marker-java.lang.String-java.lang.StackTraceElement-org.apache.logging.log4j.message.Message-java.lang.Throwable-) maybe, but that appears to be pretty low level).

However, you should check whether that `targetClass` argument for parameter `callerFQCN` is actually needed. It looks like it is intended to find the caller of the logger method and might mainly be intended for usage by logging libraries extending Log4j 1. Unless you are indeed upgrading such library, I would assume that the method is misused and a regular Log4j 2 `logger.debug(message)` would do equally well. Though it would help nonetheless if you could provide more context.